# Definitions made with \newcommand die after one use

Tags: macros

I'm using Overleaf.

I created a simple command to combine `\textbf` and `\texttt`.

```
\newcommand{\textbftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
```

The definition is in the document prelude file.

I use the `\textbftt` command elsewhere in the document, e.g., `textbftt{return}`. It seems to work fine.

However, when I edit the file where `\textbftt` is used (and the edit has nothing to do with the use of `\textbftt`) the command no longer works. The text is rendered with neither `bf` nor `tt`.

I also see an error marking in the margin (a small red box with an 'x'). The attached error message says that the command is used in a way that is inconsistent with its definition. (How can that be if it worked properly at first?)

More confusing is that if I then make an extraneous edit to the file containing the definition, e.g., add an extra space someplace in the file, the command now works properly--until I again edit the file where it is used. (The same thing happens if I use `\def` instead of `\newcommand`.)

I find myself making repeated meaningless changes to the prelude file, e.g., adding and removing an extraneous space) to see what my document looks like.

Any thoughts about what might be going on?

Are the changes to the prelude file forcing Overleaf to re-read that file--and hence the definition? Doesn't it always do that when it recompiles?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your command should work without problems and it shouldn't trigger a `Use of \textbftt doesn't match its definition`. Can you please show a compilable example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Can you see this Overleaf project: https://www.overleaf.com/3972574292hrzwtqtkysqq. (I'm not the owner, although I can ask the owner to share it.) The definition is in main.tex; the use is in body.tex (and elsewhere).

Comment: The definition in the project you linked to says `\def\textbftt[#1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}`, and not what you show in the question. With the above definition you must use the command with `\textbftt[text]` instead of `\textbftt{text}`. Change the definition to what you show in the question and it should work.

Comment: Rather than posting links to an external site, which may disappear in he future rendering your question meaningless, please give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should compile and be the smallest amount of code necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @RussAbbott The remaining errors I see are due to the usage of `\item` outside a `itemize` or `enumerate` or another list environment and due to a missing definition of `\pyth`...

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik. Now I'm even more confused. You are right about the extraneous `\item` commands. I'm in the process of getting rid of them. The main.tex file has these lines: `\newcommand{\textbftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
% \def\textbftt[#1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}' The `\def` version is commented out. I don't understand why it's different in what you see. But even more confusing. When I follow my own link, the problem does not occur! I can change body.tex and not destroy \textbftt. As I said, I'm completely confused. (I'm also a raw LaTeX newbie, as you can probably tell.)

Comment: @RussAbbott I'll post and answer explaining the difference of the two and why you should use `\newcommand{\textbftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}` instead of the `\def` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your document you have/had:

```latex
\def\textbftt[#1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
```

and in the question you said you had:

```latex
\newcommand{\textbftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
```

First things first: unless you really, *absolutely* know what you're doing, you should use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` in a document. If you look carefully, the LaTeX manual doesn't even explain the usage of `\def`, so it (sort of) doesn't belong to the system (of course it works because LaTeX runs on top of TeX, but it really shouldn't be used in an everyday document). **`\def` is for "experts"!**

Now, both of the definitions above are correct and both will work if used properly (what doesn't :-). However both define two very different commands!

#### `\newcommand`

Let's first tackle the second one, which is "easier". The syntax for `\newcommand` is:

```latex
\newcommand{<command>}[<num args>][<default>]{<replacement text>}
```

where both `[<num args>]` and `[<default>]` are optional, but the former is mandatory if the latter is to be used. `<command>` is the command name, in your case `\textbftt`, which you defined to take `<num args>=1` argument, with no optional arguments (because `<default>` is not given) and the `<replacement text>` of this command is `\textbf{\texttt{#1}}`, where `#1` is the first (and only) argument to the command, enclosed in braces (`{...}`). This all means that when you use that definition:

```latex
\textbftt{<some text>}
```

TeX will expand `\textbftt`, replacing the `#1` in the `<replacement text>` by the stuff between (balanced!) braces:

```latex
\textbf{\texttt{<some text>}}
```

which is what you want.

#### `\def`

Now the `\def` version is trickier. The syntax of `\def` is (simplifying a little):

```latex
\def<command><parameter text>{<replacement text>}
```

where `<command>` and `<replacement text>` are the same as the ones in the `\newcommand` version. The `<parameter text>` is what tricked you because, well, it's the tricky part :-)

The `<parameter text>` can be arbitrary text, with the exception of `{` and `}`, which can contain up to 9 `#` symbols followed by consecutive numbers from 1 to 9 (*i.e.,* `#1`, `#2`, ... `#9`---these are the "parameters"). Whatever you use in the `<parameter text>` except for the parameters must match *exactly* when you use the `<command>`. In your definition `\def\textbftt[#1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}`, the `<parameter text>` is `[#1]`, so whenever you use `\textbftt` TeX expects to find *exactly* a `[`, followed by arbitrary (balanced---balanced pairs of `{...}`), possibly empty, text, until the next `]`. If TeX doesn't find any of these it will say that the `Use of \textbftt doesn't match its definition`.

Now, knowing that you need to enclose the text in `[...]` instead of `{...}` you now can use the command like in the previous version:

```latex
\textbftt[<some text>]
```

then TeX will expand `\textbftt`:

```latex
\textbf{\texttt{<some text>}}
```

and you have the same result, but with a different definition and usage.

#### The catch

But now you say: "Hey, I can use `\textbftt[<some text>]` instead of `\textbftt{<some text>}`!"

Well, yes, you can. But you should not. The LaTeX manual defines that *optional* arguments should be enclosed in `[...]`, not mandatory arguments. Going against this convention makes the usage of the command counter intuitive and potentially problematic.

The other problem is that TeX knows that `{...}` are "delimiters", while `[` and `]` are just two characters just like `!` and `,` and `@` and... This means that if you need to use other `[` or `]` you need special protection to ensure that TeX does the right thing. For example:

```latex
\textbftt[some [text] with square brackets]
```

will *not* do what you want.
It will expand to:

```latex
\textbf{\texttt{some [text}} with square brackets]
```

And, finally, of course, `\newcommand` checks whether the command you are trying to create already exists and throws an error if you are about to redefine something important. `\def` just does it and you will only notice when chaos ensues.

If you search this site you'll see tons of examples of "you should've used `\newcommand` instead", so I suggest you stick to it unless you are sure of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I'm more than happy to use \newcommand. The only reason I tried \def is that \newcommand wasn't working consistently for me.

Comment: As I said above, I'm more and more confused.  My file has the \def version commented out. (It did when I posted my question.) I don't know why you saw it as the operative definition.

Comment: Also as I said above, when I followed the link I posted the problem didn't occur. I have no idea why. But I was happily editing away until I defined another \newcommand. Then the same thing happened. Both commands stopped working until I added an extraneous space to main.tex. This time, however, the error message says undefined control sequence instead of use inconsistent with the definition. I'm feeling defeated by Overleaf/LaTeX.

Comment: @RussAbbott I looked at your project again, and the problem is `Undefined control sequence \textttbf`. The command you define is `\textbftt` (the `tt` and `bf` are swapped). If you click the error message Overleaf takes you to where it happened.

Comment: A colleague noticed that the project main menu said that the main document is main_bak.tex.  At one point I tried to simplify main.tex and saved the old one and created a new one. I guess I saved the old one by renaming it from main.tex to main.bak.tex. Then I probably created a new main.tex. Overleaf must have changed the project settings to keep the old main.tex (now renamed to main_bak.tex) as the main document. When we changed the settings so that main.tex was the main document as intended, most of the problems cleared up!

Comment: It was even worse than my pervious comment indicated. Even though the project settings said to start with main_bak.tex, Overleaf starts to compile with whichever file is open!. So when I opened main.tex to add or remove an extraneous space, it would compile  main.tex and my \newcommand would work again! It wasn't the space, it was having the file open!

Comment: @RussAbbott Ouch :/ Try creating a file called `.latexmkrc` and then write `@default_excluded_files = ('main_bak.tex');` there to avoid Overleaf using it to compile. I'm not sure about this though, I don't use Overleaf much. I found it really strange (not to say impossible) that the behaviour you described was really happening. Good to know the problem is solved. If you want to you can mark this question as "solved" (see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1853/134574)).