# Custom commands with optional arguments in section title

Tags: macros, sectioning

There are many instances where I need to create my own commands and a lot of the time I also need them to have an optional argument. No problems there.

However, I needed to have one of my commands inside the title of a section and then no .pdf was produced. Here is a simplified code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifnextchar[{bracket}{parenthesis}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{\foo()}
\foo()
\section{\foo[]}
\foo[]

\end{document}
```

If `\section{\foo()}` and `\section{\foo[]}` are removed, then everything seems to work fine. Also, if you remove them, compile, get your .pdf, then add just one of them to the code, then you **still get a .pdf** even though you couldn't earlier, and if you add the second one it still complies. Always with a bunch of errors.

If I make it more complicated - let's say I have redefined a preexisting command - then not even the old definition of the command works inside the `\section` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\let\doublevowelhyphen\H
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\H}{\@ifnextchar[{\@foo}{\@ffoo}}
\def\@foo[#1]#2{#2.#1}
\def\@ffoo#1{#1.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{\doublevowelhyphen{o}}
\doublevowelhyphen{o}
\section{\H{1}}
\H{1}
\section{\H[1]{2}}
\H[1]{2}

\end{document}
```

Here I get a similar behaviour as before.

Finally, I seem to get additional errors if I'm using the `hyperref` package which I also need.

I suspect it has something to do with the `@` symbol by I don't really understand what's going on. Can someone, please, explain why this is happening?

Comment: The problem is basically what is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497356/134574). Both your commands `\foo` and `\H` are fragile and blow up when being written to the `.toc` file. You need to make them robust. Also commands with optional arguments hardly work in PDF bookmarks, so you may have to need `\texorpdfstring` from `hyperref`. If your command will have a mandatory argument (like in the second example) then you can use `xparse` and `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`. Can you explain the exact use case, please?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik They could be expandable given a mandatory argument is there ...

Comment: Have you tried prefixing `\protect` before `\H` and `\foo`?

Comment: @Mico That actually works, but it's gonna be a pain to do that every time my commands (kinda) randomly fail.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Wow, I learnt a lot from the reference you had there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little hard to answer as, despite the question title, the example given has no optional argument. (Note the `[]` following the command is typeset as text not taken as argument delimiter). However it does use the `\@ifnextchar` construct which would make it fragile, however you can hide that by declaring it as a robust command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{\@ifnextchar[{bracket}{parenthesis}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{\foo()}
\foo()
\section{\foo[]}
\foo[]

\end{document}
```

Conversely this command, that has an optional argument defined via `\newcommand` is defined to be robust, but of course has a different behaviour.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\newcommand{\foo}[1][bracket]{parenthesis}


\begin{document}

\section{\foo()}
\foo()
\section{\foo[]}
\foo[]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't really give an example matching the title exactly, but it turns out my problem was the fragility of my commands (with or without an optional argument). `\DeclareRobustCommand` actually makes things work fine for me. I didn't know that existed. Thanks.

Comment: Although I marked this as solved, could you possibly make another answer (or extend this one) explaining how `\DeclareRobustCommand` really works so that I don't misuse it?
Or maybe point me to where I could find an explanation?